# Meteor > Accounts.createUser rerender pages on every browsers

Tags: facebook, meteor

I get something I don't understand about Accounts.createUser(). When a new user signs up on my application (or when he types an already used email and get a warning alert), it causes the rerendering of the dashboard page for every browsers (and maybe for all browsers on other pages too. The thing is, we can really see that the dashboard is rerendered because I see the facebook button reappears thanks to the code below).

```
Template.dashboard.rendered = function() {
    FB.XFBML.parse(document.getElementById('facebookButton')); // render facebook like button
};
```

I spent many time to figure out why the template rerender. I hope someone have an idea. Is it a core functionality of Meteor when we use Accounts.createUser()?

```
// on the client
Accounts.createUser({email: email, password: password}, function(err) {
    if (err) {
        if (err.message === 'Email already exists. [403]') {
            Session.set('alert', {type: 'error', message: 'We\'re sorry but this email is already used.'});
        } else {
            Session.set('alert', {type: 'error', message: 'We\'re sorry but something went wrong.'});
        }
        rumble(signUpForm);
    } else {
        Session.set('alert', {type: 'success', message: 'Congrats! You\'re now a Famecoiner!'});
        unblockForm(signUpForm);
        Router.go('welcome');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue may be related to your templating HTML. When a part of a template needs to re-render, Meteor re-renders the whole template. Try putting your login HTML inside a `{{#isolate}}...{{/isolate}}` block or make it a sub-template.

Comment: I would guess your dashboard template somehow depends on the 'alert' session variable.  So when 'alert' changes, the dashboard template is re-rendered as expected.  Put the isolate around the part that uses 'alert' and the entire dashboard should no longer re-render.